# How to implement Laravel 4 Partial Views - Binding data to partial views

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, partial-views

I am debating whether I should use Laravel to build an online store.

Requirement - Show a shopping cart in sidebar with product listing in main area. i need to bind data to my partial views.

I have created a `PartialController` to display partial views.

```
class PartialController extends BaseController {

    public function showCartSummary()
    {
        $cartItems = Cart::all();   
        return View::make('partials.cartsummary', array(
            'cart' => $cartItems,
        ));
    }

    public function showProducts()
    {
        $products = Products::all();
        return View::make('partials.products', array(
            'products' => $products,
        ));
    }
}
```

I have created a shop index view to pull in the partial views

Shop.Index.Blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    @include('partials.cart')
@stop

@section('side1')
    @include('partials.products')
@stop
```

The problem is that no data is passed on to these views because partials.cart and partials.products are not being called from their own controllers.

My workaround involves querying the database within the `ShopController` and passing this to the `shop.index` view.

ShopController.php

I have also created a ShopController

```
    public function showIndex()
    {
        $cartItems = Cart::all();   
        $products = Product::all();

        return View::make('shop.index', array(
            'cartItems' => $cartItems,
            'products' => $products
        ));
    }
```

Of course, I am now repeating my db queries and I don't want to have to repeat the same queries in every controller method where multiple views are used.

What is the best way of doing this?

NB: I have over simplified database calls for the purposes of this question & there may be one or two typos / syntax errors in code, but not important for this question.

**Iteration 2:**

I have found that I can use `view composers` to create viewmodels / presenters.

shop.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    @include('partials.products')
@stop
@section('side1')
    @include('partials.cartitems')
@stop
```

Now to pass the data to the partial views:
Firstly I ditch the PartialController.php, then amend filters.php
**filters.php**

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    View::composer('partials.products', 'ProductComposer');
    View::composer('partials.cartitems', 'CartComposer');
});

class ProductComposer {
    public function compose($view)
    {
        $view->with('products', Product::all()); 
    }
}

class CartComposer {
    public function compose($view)
    {
        $view->with('cartitems', Cart::all());    
    }
}
```

This is still very messy, i don't want to stuff all my partial views into the filters.php file... Is there a proper / official way of doing this? Any examples?

Comment: the iteration2 is correct. you can make those classes in their own file and include them in the namespace. that will be cleaner.

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the  (squeaky-wheeled) shopping cart?  There are enough free and well tested options out there to allow you to get on with the interesting stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a composers.php file in your app/ directory and include it via app/start/global.php. In this file, do the View::composer calls (you do not need to put them inside App::before).

Move the composer classes into a new app/composers/ directory and add the directory to the autoloader in your composer.json.

Other than that, your use of composers is correct.

Answer (score 0):

for me 
create a abstract class ShopController extends BaseController

and in constructor() 
  write View::composer

and you can use DB::table('products')->remember(100)->get(); vs all() for the cache

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do

```
@include('partials.products', array('data'=>'here'))
```