# Mvc and php: passing variables from controller to the view

Tags: php, oop, session, model-view-controller, partial

I'm trying to implement mvc design pattern to my existing dating-web-app project. I believe I understood the concepts and created a login model and controller without any problems. Basically, I have a base controller which initiates a view object on construct. Than I use that object to send information to the view from within the controllers as method parameters. However, I couldn't decide how to send variables to the top menu view. Since this menu displays dynamic information (request count, notification count,etc) and included in every page of the application, only two options come to my mind:

- Send information to the view from every controller, which seemed like reuse of code.
- Put a seperate action in the base controller and make it called automatically when other controllers extend base controller.

Which one should I choose? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is both too broad and opinion-based. There are an infinite number of ways of solving the problem you describe.

Comment: @meagar I'm sure there are. Conceptually, what would you do?

Comment: I found partials to be a good way to go, for example:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546910/how-to-implement-laravel-4-partial-views-binding-data-to-partial-views][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546910/how-to-implement-laravel-4-partial-views-binding-data-to-partial-views

Comment: @Whiteley I'm sorry, the part I was implying is that *this question is off-topic* because it is both too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: @user2449659 seems like a starting point, thanks